# Kubernetes Ingress SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm new in k8s and can't get how to use SSL with ingress.
Here is my app yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  name: app-name
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-name
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-name
          image: dockerhub:app-name
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrypullsecret
```

And ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - sub.example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: sub.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: app-name
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
```

And my tls-secret yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: tls-secret
  namespace: default
data:
  tls.crt: |
    MIIFfD...

  tls.key: |
    MIIEvQ...
```

My app hosted on DigitalOcean but i use external DNS. I applied tls-secret by

```
kubectl apply -f tls-secret.yaml
```

And tried to open app in browser and it still not secured. Browser says that certificate is not valid  "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate"
Should I do some extra configs or i have mistake in manifests files?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ingress Controller deployment, RBAC, CRD and a service inorder to work along with what you have mentioned.

Please find the below list of resources needed inorder to expose your application to internet using ingress

- Secret (TLS Certs)
- Service (Load Balancer)
- Configmap(depends on what
  ingress controller you have used)
- Deployment(Ingress Controller) CRD
  RBAC

Please refer to my answer about ingress controllers in one of other question

[How can I identify which ingress controller is installed on my Kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206771/how-can-i-identify-which-ingress-controller-is-installed-on-my-kubernetes-cluste/76206940#76206940)

Please find the sample load balancer service below and make sure you have installed controller deployment, RBAC and crd

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
externalTrafficPolicy: Local
type: LoadBalancer
ports:
- port: 80
  targetPort: 80
  protocol: TCP
  name: http
- port: 443
  targetPort: 443
  protocol: TCP
  name: https
selector:
  app: nginx-ingress
```